# WinhttpOpenRequest returns error 998

Tags: winhttp

When I use the winhttp client application consecutive times, the WinHttpOpenRequest returns error 998.

```
bResults = WinHttpOpenRequest( hFileHttp.hConnect, L"POST", 
                                       urlCompo.lpszUrlPath, 
                                       NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                       WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 
                                       0);
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes this?

Comment: Error is [`0x000003E6` `ERROR_NOACCESS` "Invalid access to memory location."](http://alax.info/blog/1383), start with checking arguments passed to the API.

Comment: @RomanR.: so far there were no problems with the parameters, and there were no problems with the file sending process using the client application either, only after a couple of consecutive sending, that the WinHttpOpenRequest returns the system error 998